# Printing to exact size in VB6

Tags: printing, vb6

I am looking for a method to print bitmap images in VB6 at a specific pixel/mm ratio. The idea is to have a function that will print a 500 x 500 pixel image at n x n mm, a 1000 x 1000 pixel image at 2*n x 2*n mm, a 1000 x 500 at 2*n x n mm, etc.

I have searched extensively for a solution to this with little success. The most promising possible solution I have found is setting members in a DEVMODE struct, but documentation on this is very sparse. The Printer class also has some scale methods, but none sound like they do what I need.

Does anybody have an idea on how to implement this functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print Bitmap Visual Basic 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033077/print-bitmap-visual-basic-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Printer.PaintPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.compatibility.vb6.printer.paintpicture.aspx). You can specify the width and height in the parameters. Also, previously answered here, [Print Bitmap Visual Basic 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033077/print-bitmap-visual-basic-6).